# SSRS Issue with Changing Background Colour when field value = 1

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

Currently i am setting up my table to change the colour of a cell to blue if the value is 1.

I use the following experession:

```
=IIf(Fields!PassedScore.Value = 1, "CornflowerBlue", "White")
```

[image]

So as you can see from the image on some of the fields this expression is ignored. Can anyone help me solve my problem or maybe enlighten me in a known issue SSRS has.

Thanks

Comment: do you want to change the background color to the entire row based on the value of the first column?

Comment: Make sure the field you're referencing in the cell is the same one in the color expression.

Answer (score 0):

Another method of setting the colour is to use `Me.Value`. If there's any doubt that the value in the cell might differ from the value used by the BackgroundColor expression, you might want to use this method.

```
=IIF(Me.Value = 1, "CornflowerBlue", "White")
```